# javascript replace() all appearances of given string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace part of a string with a different string, but the original string has multiple instances of the string I want to replace and `replace()` only replaces the first instance.

```
newString = "New String!"
testString = testString.replace("Old String?", newString);
```

I've also tried the global flag 'g' but I think my implementation was incorrect.

Comment: would have been helpful to see your implementation of the global flag so that we can inform you on how you were doing it incorrectly.

Comment: _"and `replace()` only replaces the first instance."_ - Did you look at any documentation for `.replace()`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a good place to look for all (built-in) JS functions...and it has [some examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Examples)...

Comment: All of the answers so far are saying roughly the same thing. It seems very discourteous to downvote each of them without explanation.

Comment: All of the answers are mediocre compared to the already accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144788/400654

Comment: @KevinB - If we started downvoting all mediocre answers, there would be a lot of downvotes going around.

Comment: Maybe, mediocre was the wrong word. duplicate maybe. The accepted answer was from 5 years ago.

Comment: @HandyAndyShortStack I didn't downvote them. :/

Answer (score -1):

You should use a global regex for the first argument to `String.prototype.replace`:

```
var s = "mississippi";
var newString = s.replace(/i/g, 'u');
console.log(newString); //=> 'mussuppuppu'
```